# Command to merge all terminal windows?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, terminal, osx

Is there a terminal command that merges all open terminal windows into one window with tabs? Been searching all over the place, but have yet to find any solutions.

Comment: Currently using `terminal` on OSX.

Comment: Suggest asking on the apple SE as the solution is probably an OS X app like BetterTouchTool and nothing to do with terminal

Comment: `echo $term` returns `xterm-256color`

Answer (score 1):

in the menus of Terminal.app use Window->Merge all windows.

Comment: Pretty much what I'm going for, but I'm looking for a command I can type directly into the terminal that performs the same function.

Comment: Then you should search for ways to script menu options

Comment: i know applescripts will access menu items for example.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103621/run-applescript-from-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

This was [a requested feature](https://sourceforge.net/p/iterm/feature-requests/650/) in the original iTerm six years ago, but the only activity on it was to set the priority to low.

From poking around in [itermocil](https://github.com/TomAnthony/itermocil), I think you should be able to do it to either Terminal.app or iTerm(2) by using AppleScript.  However, I know very little about AppleScript and can't find any real documentation on it.